# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have a an issue when trying to compile my project.

I have a standalone swift project. It works PERFECTLY.

I added it to an objective-c project (as a plugin). It also works perfectly.

My swift code has no problem what so ever.

Today I needed to change some behaviour in the app delegate file. So I needed to call some of my Swift code in there.

To do this I imported the "ProjectName-Swift.h" file that xcode generates.

No problem so far, it lets me call my Swift code with autocomplete.

However when I go to build I get an error:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver'
```

The file this occurs in, is of course the PumpUp-Swift.h file. I don't create this, Xcode does. Do you know how I can fix this issue given that I can't edit this file?

Comment: I having the same issue - and am stumped. Weird thing is I am using my "ProjectName-Swift.h"in some places just fine. But when I try to include it in a UIView: broken.

Comment: Its a bug and apple doesn't give a ****. Filed bug reports, and they dont care. Ended up re-coding all my objc classes as swift because of this.